# Rewriting matrix equation into terms of $t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a matrix equation in the form of:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0       & y_{1} & \cdots                                   & y_{k} \\
y_{1}   &       &                                          &         \\
\vdots  &       & A + t(B + C) + t^2 D                     &         \\
y_{k}   &       &                                          &
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta \mu \\
\Delta \alpha_{1} \\
\cdots \\
\Delta \alpha_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
=
-
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
(t(B + C) + t^2 D)\boldsymbol{\alpha}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$

where $\Delta \mu$ is a scalar, $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ and $\Delta \boldsymbol{\alpha}$ are vectors of size $k$, and matrices
$A, B, C, D$ are of size $k\times k$.

I am looking to convert this into something of the following form:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta \mu \\
\Delta \alpha_{1} \\
\cdots \\
\Delta \alpha_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
=
G
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
t \\
t^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$

I have gone as far as converting the right side of the equation to

$$
-
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
(B + C)\boldsymbol{\alpha} & D\boldsymbol{\alpha}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
t \\ t^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
but I haven't gotten much further with the left side. I especially have trouble getting all terms containing $t$ to the right side, while keeping $\Delta \boldsymbol{\alpha}$ on the left side. Is my problem even possible to solve?

Comment: Solving the equation uniquely requires the first matrix in your equation to be invertible for all values of$~t$; as it stands it is not at all clear that it is. In addition, the inverse applied to the right hand side must be a polynomial expression in$~t$ of degree at most$~2$, which seems even less likely.

Comment: Thanks Marc. What if I add the constraint that $t \geq 0$ and remove the $t^2$ term from both sides? I can update the question to reflect those constraints if necessary.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see what difference that would make. To me it seems hight unlikely that there would be any solution at all (where $G$ is, I suppose, a matrix not depending on$~t$). Is there a reason you think there is?

Comment: These equations come up in the context of training a support vector machine (machine learning algorithm). In the simplest case, matrices A, B, C, D are related in the form
$$
A = XX^T, B = XO^T, C = OX^T, D = OO^T.
$$
If there is no perfect solution, then an approximate solution (using for example pseudoinverse) would be acceptable. In the original formulation of SVM, $t = 0$. We are trying to figure out how to update the SVM in the presence of linear additions to the training vectors in $X$. I (maybe unjustifiably) didn't specify for the sake of simplicity, my apologies.